# Object orientated strings / numbers in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

I was looking at Ruby and it has a very nice OO structure unlike PHP with C-like string functions. I was wondering if there is an extension which makes strings into objects so you could use them like this:

```
$str = "sometext";
echo "len:" . $str->length; //would print 'len: 8'
```

Comment: I doubt that's possible because of the way PHP works. Right?

Comment: ... and then you'd write `mb_strlen($str)` anyway because `->length` does not return the actual UTF-8 length of the string.  ;-)

Comment: Short answer: That's impossible with pure PHP, but possible with some special class that wraps a string variable.

Comment: It's a shame this is not implemented by default.
Same thing for arrays...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at this...

http://code.google.com/p/php-string/downloads/detail?name=string.php&can=2&q=

The class supports the extensions mbstring and iconv, and the package PHP-UTF8. It chooses the best available function for each method In addition, it provides many new methods. Some of them are: substringBetween, splice, startWith, endsWith and squeeze. It is also possible to use PHP internal functions, or custom functions, to manipulate the string.

Sample Code:

```
<?php

include('string.php');

$str = new String('sometext');
echo $str->length; //prints 8
echo $str->getLength(); //prints 8

?>
```

I have never used this class before but by looking at its documentation it has some pretty interesting methods. capitalize, charAt, compareTo, contains, etc..

Comment: But how do I make it so "abc" will create a new class?

Comment: $str = new String('abc') once you include that class in your code.

Comment: But I want to use it like I use a normal string. That's the whole point, I want all strings to be objects.

Comment: From what I know, which is not much, this is as close as you are going to get.

Comment: This answer isn't compatible with PHP 7.0, since `String` is a reserved name: `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use 'String' as class name as it is reserved`

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit late to the game, but I was looking for a library just like this and came across this question. After more investigation I found the brilliant [danielstjules/Stringy](https://github.com/danielstjules/Stringy) at GitHub.

I've looked over the documentation and the source and it looks pretty damn solid. I'd recommend taking a look at if you want a PHP String Wrapper class to make string manipulation easier. Note that this code is not a PHP extension, meaning there is no native manipulation, it is simply a wrapper.

[image: Stringy]

> A PHP string manipulation library with multibyte support. Compatible with PHP 5.3+, PHP 7, and HHVM.

A few examples:

```
s('Upper Camel-Case')->upperCamelize(); // 'UpperCamelCase'
s('What are your plans today?')->truncate(19, '...'); // 'What are your pl...'
s('foo & bar')->containsAll(['foo', 'bar']); // true
s('Ο συγγραφέας είπε')->countSubstr('α'); // 2
```

Comment: I know this might be a very old question but it seems it still true today.
From what I saw the suggested module is not supported any more and I saw a copy of it that seems to be supported.
Packagist: https://packagist.org/packages/voku/stringy
Git Hub: https://github.com/voku/Stringy

His version might have more methods compared to the original one as well.
Thanks to Lars Moelleken aka [@voku](https://github.com/voku)

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to you could create your own String wrapper class that has all the string based methods and calculated attributes that you could possibly want. Edit: In the same way that Java has wrapper classes for some data types.

Comment: Actually, there is no primitive string type in Java -- all strings are objects of the `java.lang.String` class.

Comment: @casablanca Well, this IS a PHP question and not a Java question. Does the PHP part of my answer still stand as valid or does the answer deserve to be voted down based on my bad example? I may have been thinking of char in my head and got confused.

Comment: I'm sorry but it wasn't me who downvoted you. In fact, I gave you a +1 now to negate the downvote and also because you actually did answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

While Jose Vega suggested a good solution for your problem, there is a farily minor performance issue with the approach. I've whipped up a test for this. While each solution performs well enough for practical purposes, there is a difference.

EDIT: So anyway, since this is neither Ruby, nor Java, nor Smalltalk, you'd be better off using the provided tools than trying to bend the language to meet your expectations. Mostly for performance reasons (because native tools are usually written in C or are low-level enough to have very little performance impact, although it's not always true), and for readability: the community is used to seeing mb_strlen() or strlen(), and other string-related functions.

Here's the code I used for benchmarking:

http://pastebin.com/Q4BfzQtj

Results:

```
====> Test run 0
And here are the results:
Test with {} = 0.00097203254699707
Test with strlen() = 0.0030488967895508
Test with mb_strlen() = 0.0031669139862061
Test with String1 object = 0.012485027313232
Test with String object = 0.036020040512085


====> Test run 1
Test with {} = 0.00095200538635254
Test with strlen() = 0.0029759407043457
Test with mb_strlen() = 0.0031669139862061
Test with String1 object = 0.012346982955933
Test with String object = 0.036028146743774


====> Test run 2
Test with {} = 0.0009617805480957
Test with strlen() = 0.0029959678649902
Test with mb_strlen() = 0.0031518936157227
Test with String1 object = 0.012416124343872
Test with String object = 0.037784099578857


====> Test run 3
Test with {} = 0.00081610679626465
Test with strlen() = 0.0025439262390137
Test with mb_strlen() = 0.0027410984039307
Test with String1 object = 0.010634183883667
Test with String object = 0.030903100967407


====> Test run 4
Test with {} = 0.00081205368041992
Test with strlen() = 0.0025379657745361
Test with mb_strlen() = 0.0027129650115967
Test with String1 object = 0.010583162307739
Test with String object = 0.031081914901733


====> Test run 5
Test with {} = 0.000823974609375
Test with strlen() = 0.0025639533996582
Test with mb_strlen() = 0.0026860237121582
Test with String1 object = 0.010586023330688
Test with String object = 0.030833959579468
```

Comment: You create a new String Object inside the for loops in each cycle, but when you use the native string type, you define it just once at the beginning of the test. This, of course has an impact on performance.

Answer (score 0):

There is [SplString](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splstring.php). But it's not available in PHP 5.3 yet. And I doubt it's of much use if it comes around, since it harbors no useful methods whatsoever. Maybe one could built upon it. But then that's only for strings. PHP is built upon scalars, and using it fully object-oriented is not possible at this time.

Answer (score 0):

It's 2014 and SplString is still not default in PHP. I'd take a look at:

https://github.com/nikic/scalar_objects

It's an extension, so you have to install it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but I think it is still valid.

Based on my research I think the [danielstjules/Stringy](https://github.com/danielstjules/Stringy) is the best alternative but from what I saw it is not actively supported. From one of the issues I found a copy that is supported and seem to also have PHP 8 return types and is more up to date with last PHP versions and that is [voku/Stringy](https://github.com/voku/Stringy) (GitHub) or [voku/stringy](https://packagist.org/packages/voku/stringy) (Packagist)

From the lib Stringy readme:

> A PHP string manipulation library with multibyte support. Compatible with PHP 7+

> 100% compatible with the original "Stringy" library, but this fork is optimized for performance and is using PHP 7+ features.

Thanks to  aka [Lars Moelleken](https://github.com/voku) for his support on this.