# PHP variable assign back to self

Tags: php

So in PHP, there's all sorts of [assignment operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php), (like `$a += $b`, or `$str .= $another_str`), but is there a way to do such a thing with the built-in functions (or others, even)?

For example, is it possible (or even worthwhile) to shorten this:

`$str = strtolower($str)`

Object-wise, we'd normally do something like:

`$str->toLower()` (Pseudo-code)

Where the value of `$str` would then be the lower case'd value.

but does PHP have and/or do anything like that?

EDIT: In regards to this being string-specific, that was just an example. I'm also curious if it would be possible to "shorten":

`$array = array_values($array)`

This is more out of curiosity than anything else, since I know these functions all operate with a return value. The question is more about whether there is an *operator* that assigns the return of the function back to the same variable name.

```
$a += 4;
// yields same result as
$a = $a + 4;
```

But is there an operator which can do the same as the top line for things other than math, concatenation, and bitwise. (I'm fairly certain the answer is "no", but the PHP world is vast)

Comment: to an extent: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4423721/2119863

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai Awesome link! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Unless a built-in takes a variable by-reference (like [`sort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)), the built-in will return its result for you to make the assignment yourself (like [`strtolower`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)).

If you want a OO String behavior, you can use [`Stringy`](https://github.com/danielstjules/Stringy):

```
s('string')->toTitleCase()->ensureRight('y') == 'Stringy'
```

If you're looking to shorten array calls, the [pipe operator RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/pipe-operator) discussion may interest you:

```
$ret = scandir($arg)
    |> array_filter($$, function($x) { return $x !== '.' && $x != '..'; })
    |> array_map(function ($x) use ($arg) { return $arg . '/' . $x; }, $$)
    |> getFileArg($$)
    |> array_merge($ret, $$);
```

> This clearly, and unambiguously shows `scandir()` as the initial source of data, that it goes through an `array_filter` to avoid recursion, an `array_map` to requalify the paths, some local function, and finally a merge to combine the result with a collector variable.

Answer (score 0):

No because the string is not an object, it's a language construct.